# vb.net Linq statement to c#

Tags: linq

I am trying to convert this statement in vb.net Linq:

```
Dim exchangeTradingCapacity = (
From ts In db_context.TRADE_SUMMARies _
Join el In db_context.EXECUTION_LISTs On ts.TRADE_ID Equals el.TRADE_ID _
                                     And ts.TRADE_PART_INDEX Equals el.TRADE_PART_INDEX _
                                     And ts.VERSION Equals el.TRADE_VERSION _
Join oe In db_context.ORDER_EXECUTIONs On oe.EXECUTION_ID Equals ts.CONTRIBUTOR_REF _
Where rootOrdersToInclude.Distinct.Contains(el.ROOT_ORDER_ID) _
  And el.TRADE_VERSION = (From el1 In db_context.EXECUTION_LISTs _
                          Where el1.TRADE_ID = el.TRADE_ID _
                            And el1.TRADE_PART_INDEX = el.TRADE_PART_INDEX _
                            And el1.ROOT_ORDER_ID = el.ROOT_ORDER_ID _
                          Select el1.TRADE_VERSION).Max() _
Group oe By Key = oe.EXCHANGE_TRADING_CAPACITY Into Group _
Select Key
).ToList
```

My attempt to convert it to c# has thus far been unsuccessful:

```
var exchangeTradingCapacity =
(from ts in dbContext.TRADE_SUMMARies
 join e1 in dbContext.EXECUTION_LISTs on
                    new
                    {
                        ts.TRADE_ID,
                        ts.TRADE_PART_INDEX,
                        ts.VERSION
                    }
                    equals
                    new
                    {
                        e1.TRADE_ID,
                        e1.TRADE_PART_INDEX,
                        VERSION = e1.TRADE_VERSION
                    }
join oe in dbContext.ORDER_EXECUTIONs on ts.CONTRIBUTOR_REF equals oe.EXECUTION_ID
where rootOrdersToInclude.Distinct().Contains(e1.ROOT_ORDER_ID) &&
      e1.TRADE_VERSION == (from el1 in dbContext.EXECUTION_LISTs
                           where el1.TRADE_ID == el.TRADE_ID &&
                                 el1.TRADE_PART_INDEX == el.TRADE_PART_INDEX &&
                                 el1.ROOT_ORDER_ID == el.ROOT_ORDER_ID
                           select el1.TRADE_VERSION).Max()
group oe by oe.EXCHANGE_TRADING_CAPACITY into theKey
select theKey
).ToList();
```

It appears that for some reason, 'el' is out of scope when inside the subquery.  Can someone point me to the error of my ways?  It seems like this should work.

Comment: Try http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Comment: Tried that, doesn't work.  Gives an error processing the statement.

Comment: You don't have "el" declared anywhere. You have "e1" at the top of your query, then you're doing "el" on the last subquery.

Comment: OMG... okay it's officially to late to be coding.  Thank you napo.  If you want to submit this as an answer, I will swallow my shame and give credit where credit is due.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an alias el (letter L), only the alias e1 (number 1).